# How to convert binary into decimal using <bitset> library?

Tags: c++, binary

I use this simple code to convert a decimal into binary :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    unsigned int n;
    cout << "# Decimal:  "; cin >> n; cout << endl;
    bitset<16>binary(n);
    cout << endl << "# Binary:  " << binary << endl;

    system("Pause"); return 0;
}
```

How to convert "binary" into decimal and assign the value to other variable ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::bitset::to_ulong()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong) ?

Comment: If you want to convert a ‘binary string’ you don't *have to* use a bitset; you could use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or one of its cousins) with base 2.

Comment: `<bitset>` is not a library, by the way. It is part of a library (the standard library).

Comment: :D . Okay , thank you for your patient . Yes , I was looking for .to_ulong().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is not "a decimal". I think you have a misconception of what numbers are, based on the default output representation used by IOStreams. They are numbers. Not decimal strings, binary strings, hexadecimal strings, octal strings, base-64 strings, or any kind of strings. But *numbers*.

The way you choose to represent them on output is entirely orthogonal to the way they are stored internally (which is, actually, base-2 not decimal), so it is highly likely that these "conversions" you're trying to do are inappropriate.

However, if you wish to extract an integer from a `std::bitset` instance, you may do so using [the `to_ulong()` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong).

**Get into the habit of using the documentation.**

Comment: Thank you. I will do my best and I will learn much more about this topic. :)